# How to simplify this bash shell code

Tags: regex, bash, shell, if-statement, grep

This is my code

```
if  grep -q $lines scanHistory;then
    echo -n ''
else
    if grep -q $lines waiting;then
        echo -n ''
    else
        Download $lines
        echo "---$lines was download successfully"
    fi
fi
```

my purpoes is if $line can't be found in both scanHistory and waiting, then run Download.

I had try to make This code more simplily, and write **if** as

**if grep -qv $lines scanHistory && grep -qv $lines waiting; then**

**....**

but a failured....

Comment: and the failure message was...?

Comment: Rather than using echo as a no-op, you can use ':'

Comment: FWIW you can also say `elif ... fi` instead of `else if ... fi; fi`, but William Pursell has an even better answer.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
if ! grep -q $lines scanHistory && ! grep -q $lines waiting; then ...
```

The initial attempt using grep -v failed because
grep -v succeeds if any line of the input does not match the pattern.

Comment: You could compress it down to a single grep of both files (`if ! grep -q $lines scanHistory waiting; then ...`), but in this case I'd say that's less readable and it's better to leave the grep runs separate with explicit logic around them. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want

```
  if ! ( grep -q $lines scanHistory || grep -q $lines waiting ) ; then

  ....
```

The problem is that -v doesn't work the way you think it should

When you `grep nonexistant file`, you get 1, it didn't find it,  but when you `grep -v nonexistant file` the return code is 0 because all the other lines in `file` DID negative-match 'nonexistant.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    grep -q -e "$lines" scanHistory -e "$lines" waiting
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] # Check if the above command is a success or not, if not run downlaod.
    then
        <run_Download>
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash short circuiting operators `&&` and `||`:

```
grep -q $lines scanHistory || 
  grep -q $lines waiting || 
  Download $lines &&
  echo "---$lines was download successfully"
```

It can be put on a single line, as bellow, but the above is more readable:

```
grep -q $lines scanHistory || grep -q $lines waiting || Download $lines && echo "---$lines was download successfully"
```